# Can I use zinc roll flashing for a sill pan and head flashing?

Tags: doors, windows, flashing

I live in a relatively remote area and am unable to find aluminum roll flashing or pre-formed flashing profiles locally. What I can get is "zinc" roll flashing as is normally used for roofing.

Can I use that to form sill pans for my exterior doors? I'm also thinking of using it for drip cap for my windows.

It is a new build, but the windows and doors are reclaimed, so a variety of materials: vinyl, wood, and aluminum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not optimal, the zinc roll can be used.  I would just check that it doesn't contact any dissimilar metal to prevent galvanic action. Of course that would be preferred with any metal.  Of course use zinc plated nails if nailing.